# Using Symfony's serializer library to use a value in a sub-object

Tags: json, symfony, serialization

I am using https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer standalone and not with Symfony. I have two entity classes as follows where `SomeProperty` is a sub-object to `MyEntity`:

```
class MyEntity {
    private $id, $name, $some_property;
    public function getId() {return $this->id;}
    public function getName(){return $this->name;}
    public function getSomeProperty(){return $this->some_property;}
}

class SomeProperty {
    private some_sub_property;
    public function getSomeSubProperty(){return $this->some_sub_property;}
}
```

I can successfully perform the default serialization of the object which results in  the following JSON:

```
{
    "id":123,
    "name":"foo",
    "some_property" : {
        "some_sub_property: "bar"
    }
}
```

But instead, I wish to include a property in the `SomeProperty` sub-object at the same level as the other properties in `MyEntity` such as:

```
{
    "id":123,
    "name":"foo",
    "mySubproperty": "bar"
}
```

I've tried about one hundred variations of XML to define the serialization and they are all somewhat similar to the follows, however, they result in including `id` and `name` but not `mySubproperty`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<serializer>
    <class name="NS\App\Domain\Entity\MyEntity">
        <xml-namespace prefix="atom" uri="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"/>
        <property name="id"/>
        <property name="name"/>
        <virtual-property
            method="getSomeProperty"
            access-type="public_method"
            accessor-getter="getSomeSubProperty"
            serialized-name="mySubproperty"
        />
    </class>
</serializer>
```

How is this accomplished?  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `@VirtualProperty` annotation if it's not a field you use elsewhere. If you use it, add `@Exclude` on `getSomeProperty()` and add a virtual property with another name.

```php
    /**
     * @Serializer\VirtualProperty()
     */
    public function getSomeProperty()
    {
        return $this->getSomeSubProperty();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Bloops.  Been trying to get this working for hours with no success.  I added some more content to my original post.  Could you take a look?

Comment: Not sure why you would use xml with manual configuration... This is a pain to read and debug. However your class should already include a virtual property in code, MyEntity should have a `getSomeSubProperty()` getter which returns the sub property. Your xml defines an output but not the logic which is done by php.

Comment: Thanks Bloops.  I get it now.  The XML documentation is a bit tricky and misleading.

Comment: Just tried using VirtualProperty and it works great.  Also tried using `@Accessor(getter="getSomeProperty")` and it also works great.  Why wouldn't one just use `Assessor` as it could then be used for deserialization as well?